# Como só receber gets de um determinado IP

Tags: php

Tenho que receber GETs com informações importantes, e só pode ser via GET e não via POST. Eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de receber os GETs de outro servidor, apenas se esse servidor tive um determinado IP.

Como poderei fazer isso?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a variável global `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Ela irá informar o IP de onde a página está sendo requisitada. Lembre-se que se você usa CloudFlare ou algum outro mecanismo similar, ele poderá alterar o conteúdo do `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

No caso do CloudFlare, isso acontece no plano gratuito e o IP original que fez a requisição é colocado em outra variável chamada `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']`

Então o código final ficaria mais ou menos isso (a julgar pelas suas necessidades):

```
<?php

$requestIP = (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : null;

if ($requestIP !== null && $requestIP === '127.0.0.1') {
    //seu código aqui
}
```

Lembre-se também de trocar o IP 127.0.0.1 presente na condição pelo IP que será permitido.

Comment: Aquele IP, é o IP de onde quero receber o get certo?

Comment: Se você esta fazendo `$requestIP === '127.0.0.1'` e `$requestIP` for igual a `null`, automaticamente não sera `false`?

Comment: Qual é a função exata para pegar o IP?

Comment: @Gonçalo eu falei na resposta... O IP de quem está fazendo a requisição não vem em uma função e sim numa variável, a variável $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert psé, é costume, mas não muda nada, além disso, da pra adaptar para colocar uma lista de IPs invés de apenas um.

Comment: Me fale uma coisa, o usuário consegue manipular o ip, para que fique igual ao do servidor?

Comment: @Gonçalo se a conexão for feita usando a internet, não. Se for na intranet, sim. Isso acontece porque não pode existir mais de uma maquina conectada na mesma rede com o mesmo IP e, a internet é uma rede.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, o usuário consegue por o ip dele igual ao da maquina?

Comment: Não consigo encontrar palavras mais simples pra explicar. Se você quer garantir a autenticidade da requisição $_GET, você pode enviar junto com ela uma key, que seria secreta. A key seria nada mais, nada menos que um novo valor passado via $_GET o qual você teria que verificar no servidor de destino, exemplo: http://exemplo.com.br/?nome=clayderson&key=109390123, lembrando que isso só vale pra requisições feitas por um servidor, as quais os usuários não poderão ver.

Comment: Certo, então posso fazer uma verificação se a key e o ip forem iguais aos encontrados, assim se realizará o get certo?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira a utilização da key de nada adianta se essa não for randômica, se for sempre a mesma pouco mudará. O melhor seria ele explicar o objectivo para ajudarmos numa possível solução.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes se for utilizada da maneira correta, será tão eficaz quanto qualquer outra solução proposta.

Answer (score 4):

É possível sim, o PHP permite verificar qual é o IP da máquina que fez a requisição, entretanto se isso é algum sistema de "segurança", não faça tal porque o utilizador pode simular um IP utilizando um proxy e assim dar a volta ao sistema.

Nunca confie em informações enviadas pelo cliente, elas podem ser manipuladas.

Toda informação relevante sobre IP pode ser encontrada no array $_SERVER. O caminho mais simples para pegar o endereço IP de seus visitantes é com o código a seguir:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Essa solução não é totalmente precisa, pois se o utilizador estiver em uma conexão utilizando servidor proxy, o IP que você obterá será o do servidor proxy e não o endereço IP real do usuário.

É possível obter resultados mais precisos. Os servidores proxy trazem no cabeçalho HTTP uma propriedade que armazena o IP original. O nome deste campo é `X-Forwarded-For` ou `Client-Ip`. Se um destes campos estiver presente no cabeçalho HTTP, então você pode ler os seus valores através do array `$_SERVER`:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

//Verifica se o IP é permitido
if($ip==xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) {
    //verifica se os dados foram enviados via GET
    if(isset($_GET["XPTO"])) {
        echo 'O IP é correto e os dados foram enviados via GET!';
    }
}
```

**Entretanto os valores de `X_Forwarded_For` e `Client_Ip` não são 100% confiáveis, pois é possível manipular esses valores. Devido à isso não podemos usar somente a verificação de IP para aplicações e soluções de segurança.**

Comment: As pessoas conseguem simular um ip que seja igual ao ip de uma maquina minha?

Comment: @Gonçalo sim, é possível simular qualquer IP.